# Type universe cannot resolve assembly: Uno.UI, Version=255.255.255.255 Platform Uno

Tags: c#, uwp, cross-platform, uno-platform

I've not been able to find the cause of this but the repo scenario I have is create a new project uno project.  Set your startup project as UWP. Set your mininmum version of windows to 1809 and then build using release build. The project won't run and I get that error.

Type universe cannot resolve assembly: Uno.UI, Version=255.255.255.255

It works just fine in debug mode.

I'm fishing for any ideas as google searches aren't turning up anything useful.